# Is it possible to use Cruise Control with VB6?

Tags: vb6, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol

I'm working on a visual basic 6 project and I would like to use a continuous integration software ... does anyone knows if its possible to use Cruise Control with VB6 ? If not ... is there another software that would do the job ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course you can use CruiseControl with VB6.  You just have to have an ANT build file that builds your VB6 project.  A target including something like the following, changed for your specific filenames and directories, should work, assuming that vb6.exe is on the path.

```
<exec dir="ApplicationDir" executable="vb6.exe" failonerror="true">
  <arg line="ProjectFile.vbp /MAKE /OUT build.log"/>
</exec>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason you can't. CC.Net doesn't actually compile anything. It's just the engine that initiates the build process. If you can build via commandline then you can build it via CC.Net.

You might want to look at Nant to do source code retrieval and the execution of the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Build Pro](http://www.kinook.com/VisBuildPro).  Works very well (in that was designed for) with VB6, as well as working with modern technology as well.  Understands how and when to properly build ActiveX controls so that you don't have ActiveX dll hell (manages Project and Binary compatibility).  Definitely worth the money if you are doing large scale VB development with many controls that you build yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try Teamcity from Jetbrains. Works better with microsoft technology like sourcesafe. Not sure about vb6 but you can always use a wrapper script.